# Type inference using extended type in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a factory, that should return a function, based on provided enum key. 
This is done in switch case and all the functions there has different payloads.

The goal I'm trying to achieve is to provide such typing to that function, that it will implicitly validate all the type of the payload and return type of the factory. See example below:

```js
// the list of keys that are used for creation
enum keys {
    key1 = 1,
    key2 = 2
}
// here are interfaces, that tie each key with payload, that should be provided.
// Actually, payload is way more complex (another interfaces) but let's keep it simple
interface Test1 {
    key: keys.key1;
    payload: string;
}
interface Test2 {
    key: keys.key2;
    payload: number;
}

// this is the type, that comes to the function below
type tests = Test1 | Test2;


interface ReturnTypeOfTest1 { returnedObject1: number; }
interface ReturnTypeOfTest2 { returnedObject2: string; }
// this is how I'm configuring what should be returned depending on the key 
// the return type is set to "ResourceModel", which infers a key from a function payload
// and identifies what exactly it should return
interface ModelOfTest {
    [keys.key1]: ReturnTypeOfTest1;
    [keys.key2]: ReturnTypeOfTest2;
}
type ResourceModel<R extends keys> = ModelOfTest[R];
```

`ResourceModel` type is created based on another stackoverflow question [Typescript: Return type of function based on input value (enum)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52593184/typescript-return-type-of-function-based-on-input-value-enum/52593348#52593348)

Using type above I can either validate the type of the payload, but loose the validation of the return type:

```js
function getTest(t: tests): any{
    switch (t.key) {
        case keys.key1: {
            const data = t.payload; // is string
            return {returnedObject1: 123 };
        } case keys.key2: {
            const data = t.payload; // is number
            return {returnedObject2: '123' };

        }
    }
}
getTest({key: keys.key1, payload: '1' }); // ReturnTypeOfTest1 | ReturnTypeOfTest2
```

Or get a proper return type, but loose a validation inside a switch case:

```js
function getTest<T extends tests>(t: T): ResourceModel<T['key']> {
    switch (t.key) {
        case keys.key1: {
            const d = t.payload; // string | number
            return {returnedObject1: 123}; // also an error here, because it wants me to return both ReturnTypeOfTest1 & ReturnTypeOfTest2
        } case keys.key2: {
            const d = t.payload; // string | number
            return null;

        }
    }
}
 getTest({key: keys.key2, payload: 1 }); // ReturnTypeOfTest2
```

Is there a way to type this thing correctly? Would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Let the compiler infer the return type. A function explicitly typed as returning `any` indicates a misunderstanding in 99% of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a missing feature in TypeScript (see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085)); the compiler cannot reason very well about an unspecified generic type parameter, such as `T` is inside the implementation of `getTest()`.  When you *call* `getTest()`, `T` is specified, and the return type is computed properly then.  But when you *implement* `getTest()`, `T` is still an unspecified/unresolved type parameter, and the compiler essentially gives up.  Specifically, it does not try to use [control-flow-based type analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) to narrow `T extends Test1 | Test2` to `Test1` or `Test2` based on the value of `t.key`.  This means that at present, generic type signatures like this are more useful to function callers than they are to function implementers.

Perhaps someday there will be a solution to this in the language.  For now, there are workarounds.  The one that I use most often in this case is to add a single [overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to the function.  Let the callers see the generic overload signature that's useful for them, while the implementation sees the non-generic union-typed signature that's useful for it:

```
// call signature, seen by callers
function getTest<T extends tests>(t: T): ResourceModel<T['key']>;
// implementation signature, seen only by implementation
function getTest(t: tests): ResourceModel<keys> {
  switch (t.key) {
    case keys.key1: {
      const d = t.payload; // string 
      const ret: ResourceModel<keys.key1> = { returnedObject1: 123 };
      return ret;
    } case keys.key2: {
      const d = t.payload; // number
      const ret: ResourceModel<keys.key2> = { returnedObject2: '123' };
      return ret;
    }
  }
}
```

This still isn't truly type safe; the above would not complain if you switched around the `return` statements so that `ReturnTypeOfTest1` comes back for `Test2` and vice versa.  But it's close to the best we can do here, at least for now, so you need to be careful in your implementation.

Let's just make sure the call works as desired:

```
getTest({ key: keys.key1, payload: "1" }); // ReturnTypeOfTest1
getTest({ key: keys.key2, payload: 1 }); // ReturnTypeOfTest2
```

Looks good.  Anyway, I hope this helps; good luck!

[Playground Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-BTQHEEkl2V6DfRQLlSdw6FmePSfJGYEWfWyeaSJoRaKhwHSAERKpAJcgOACyaFycC7zl8kAQrG8lgwNkIxB8GAyIiXjOZ4FZwVCPzoeOGDVyVgQaZpk9cfXs4CqO1z8USDH1jZlU1OsGHo-dV1AMIA2vCrz4LIAC6TzOo2rrQN+KAfOoAFiEBeAaGBireqqUEwYGOLNk6jj9kOI4cgAPAqoB9NYFYbGIAB82ifhyWF-gqIHIriRisBUcC5um3CkD6ZK5tAAgLHgbBcQuvAbiy1aAsqwrEec5G9JRdCEPy4BIDRAzgE85yzOB+E+oRo6KX+qz3KsIE0Z8Rj7N00DUlYnDVnsgJ8Sqgm0CJPC3skYn2T0TngC5fDSVusnyVcOlPBpSAGWhfbGdADFwMR8J0TCSD+OAM6DOASHzDC0icbQzxIZav7qNIJU8CgpbaAVqKRLaRj-Fm1U1Sm9X6oZSUDilRFpYBbx0Uo4gNr6dDGmaFpPLIGgAMx2siNXSM+qpFqt0h6OJZUjfgQZVWttXcPVDBKE1u71K1YAYlinWnT1yp9QRg2mQdyFjb+k2GtN-qlEdqwLYtqwrY9v1bZ1Bg7fo0pyeAwoDBN9xwohbw1NdvygF2shdnasy3WhLqatqVyyLwCNIyj+BowQSEaJjdTY-IeiE6ARgQRhpMekAA)